# Customizing a list

Tags: lists

I have several lists, I want all of them to have `{\labelwidth}{2cm}`, and `{\labelsep}{1cm}`. How can I do it, instead of writing the following everywhere?

```
\begin{list}{\stepcounter{enumi} Person \arabic{enumi}:\ }
{
\setlength{\labelwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
}
\end{list}
```

I tried this with no success

```
\let\oldlist\list
\renewcommand{\list}
{
\setlength{\labelwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
\oldlist
}
```

it is buggy, the item numbers seems mixed up. What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `enumitem` and the code from your previous question.

You can use

```
\setlist{labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=1cm}
```

and these values will be used for all your lists.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist{labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 5 + 7 = 12
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 2 * 2 = 4
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
\item 5 + 7 = 12
\item 9 + 1 = 10
\item 2 * 2 = 4
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you want different behaviors for different types of lists, you have to specify the optional argument of `\setlist`. For example

```
\setlist[enumerate]{labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=1cm}
\setlist[itemize]{labelwidth=2cm,labelsep=2cm}
```

gives you this result

[image]

Comment: how can I modify, if I want enumerate and itemize to have different margins?

Comment: @EmmetB added in the answer